# Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu inside grid not positioned correctly

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm pretty certain I'm doing something wrong here but can you tell why in the code below part of the dropdown menu appears off-screen? 
BTW when scrolling (in this case horizontally) the menu position is updated to the correct position.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           butt
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item">This is one thing yes it is one thing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item">This is one thing yes it is one thing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item">This is one thing yes it is one thing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item">This is one thing yes it is one thing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item">This is one thing yes it is one thing</a>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zL9mn455/7/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `dropdown-menu-right` to the `dropdown-menu` div.